# Program lags when using ping request

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, winforms

I have a program that I created in visual basic that shows, real-time, whether a connection is active or not. It does this by pinging the connection. If it receives a response, a block next to the connection name lights up green. If it doesn't receive a response, the block turns red.
An example of my coding follows;

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping("10.128.73.84") Then
    Button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(92, 194, 92)
Else
    Button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(181, 64, 67)
End If
```

When all of the connections are active and green, the program works quickly and smoothly. The more disconnected, the slower and slower it runs; to the point where it becomes unusable.

I've noticed that if I create a button that requests a ping response every time I click it, it works very quickly when there is something connected. I'm guessing that this is because it receives a response after only one request, whereas if it's disconnected, it sends multiple requests and only gives up after a certain amount.

My question is: am I doing something wrong/using the ping request incorrectly? Or is there another way of getting the results I want without basically having to cause the program to freeze.

Comment: that is exactly why ping is used with different threads to bypass this exact issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887422/vb-net-pinging-on-multiple-threads also make sure you set a reasonable timeout.

Comment: What's happening is that you are executing this code (and thus doing the ping) on the UI thread. Since the UI thread is the one that displays your UI and handles user interaction, that thread is blocked until the ping completes. The solution is to do the ping on a background thread.

Comment: Manually do a `ping` from the command line when one of the monitored servers is down and note how long it takes. Now, multiply that amount of time by the number of down servers... `ping` has a default timeout period after which it decides that the packet is lost, 4 lost packets (in the Windows implementation) is usually considered `down`. If you're willing to use a shorter timeout and potentially get some false positives, look to see if there's a timeout you can set on the `ping` command.

Comment: @CodyGray or just asynchronously. Seems a `Task` is all that's needed.. and it's easier to work with than a `Thread` =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an asynchronous example in C#, that does the work on a background thread.

```
private async void _btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bool reachable = false;

  try
  {
    _btnPing.Enabled   = false;
    _btnPing.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
      reachable = await SendPingAsync(_tbIPAddress.Text, cts.Token);
    }

    if (reachable)
      _btnPing.BackColor = Color.Lime;
    else
      _btnPing.BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("Form1._btnPing_Click exception: " + ex);
  }
  finally
  {
    _btnPing.Enabled = true;
  }
}

private async Task<bool> SendPingAsync(string ipAddress, CancellationToken cancelToken, int timeout = 5000)
{
  var taskPing = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
  {
    bool reachable = false;

    try
    {
      Ping    p = new Ping();
      var res   = p.Send(ipAddress, timeout);
      reachable = (res.Status == IPStatus.Success);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("Form1.SendPingAsync exception: " + ex);
    }

    return reachable;

  }, cancelToken);

  await taskPing;

  return taskPing.Result;
}
```

If the `Button` _*btnPing* is clicked, it gets the target IP address from the `TextBox` _*tbIPAddress* and performs the asynchronous ping operation.